# Specific question about AMQP priority queues in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, priority-queue

There is a specific detail about priority queues that I can't find a definitive answer on. RabbitMQ documentation states that:

- A priority queue is created by using `x-max-priority`, and recommends setting the value between 1 and 5 (or 1 and 10 in some places).
- Messages with higher priority are delivered first.
- A message with a priority value higher than `x-max-priority` for the queue is capped at the value `x-max-priority`.
- A message with no priority value is given a value of 0.

If I create a queue with, for example, `x-max-priority` of 3, does this mean that I actually have four priority levels (0 through 3), which also assumes that 0 is the lowest priority? What about a `x-max-priority` of 1--does that give me two priority levels (0 and 1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. My understanding is that it's a zero-based numbering system. Messages sent without a `priority` key are assigned `priority: 0`, which is the lowest priority level.

> If I create a queue with, for example, x-max-priority of 3, does this mean that I actually have four priority levels (0 through 3), which also assumes that 0 is the lowest priority?

Correct.

> What about a x-max-priority of 1--does that give me two priority levels (0 and 1)?

Correct.